# Firebase FCM Cloud Messaging click action link not working

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

We have an Angular PWA frontend and a .Net Core backend, which use Firebase Cloud Messaging for sending push notifications to the end user (web).

In Angular, we use FCM for notifications. The service worker works as expected, for foreground and background push notifications.

In Angular, we use Firebase@9.6.9, in .Net Core, we use FirebaseAdmin@2.2.0.

This is working fine for normal notification content (title, body, image), but we want to add **click handling** as well. The notification is build in the backend and has the following structure. The domain of the link is the same as the webapp.

```
var message = new Message()
{
    // Token
    Token = registrationToken,

    // Basic notification template to use across all platforms
    Notification = new Notification
    {
        Title = cloudMessage.Title,
        Body = cloudMessage.Body
    },

    // Webpush protocol options
    Webpush = new WebpushConfig
    {
        FcmOptions = new WebpushFcmOptions
        {
            Link = cloudMessage.Link

        }
    }
};
```

This is what we see in Chrome dev when intercepting the push notification (stripped data obviously).

```
{
  "from": "",
  "priority": "normal",
  "notification": {
    "title": "Title",
    "body": "Body",
    "click_action": "https://linktoazureapp"
  },
  "fcmMessageId": ""
}
```

When we click the notification, nothing happens. We tested this on different OS (Windows, Android, iOS) and different browsers (Chrome, Brave, Safari, Firefox), but the result is always the same, clicking or tapping the notification removes it and does nothing else. Having a browser or the PWA open, standby or completely closed makes no difference.

Firebase throws no errors, the object is structured according to how Firebase Cloud Messaging works and what it expects. We followed the Firebase API documentation, so clicking the notification should open the browser or PWA, but it does nothing.

Comment: Is your link an https link? I just ask, as it seems you replaced the value of the intercepted push notification with a sample link.

Comment: Yes, we only use https